# Mongodb map reduce across 2 collection

Tags: mongodb, join, mapreduce, schema-design

Let say we have user and post collection. In post collection, vote store the user name as a key.

```
db.user.insert({name:'a', age:12});
db.user.insert({name:'b', age:12});
db.user.insert({name:'c', age:22});
db.user.insert({name:'d', age:22});

db.post.insert({Title:'Title1', vote:[a]});
db.post.insert({Title:'Title2', vote:[a,b]});
db.post.insert({Title:'Title3', vote:[a,b,c]});
db.post.insert({Title:'Title4', vote:[a,b,c,d]});
```

We would like to group by the post.Title and find out the count of vote in different user age.

```
> {_id:'Title1', value:{ ages:[{age:12, Count:1},{age:22, Count:0}]} }
> {_id:'Title2', value:{ ages:[{age:12, Count:2},{age:22, Count:0}]} }
> {_id:'Title3', value:{ ages:[{age:12, Count:2},{age:22, Count:1}]} }
> {_id:'Title4', value:{ ages:[{age:12, Count:2},{age:22, Count:2}]} }
```

I have searched through and doesn't find a way to access 2 collection in mongodb mapreduce.
Could it be possible to achieve in re-reduce?

I know it is much simple to embedded the user document in post, but it is not a nice way to do as the real user document have many properties. If we include the simplify version of user document, it will limit the dimension of analysis.

```
{Title:'Title1', vote:[{name:'a', age:12}]}
```

Comment: It is not possible to perform a map-reduce on multiple collection. Please also explain your rationale when you say "it is not nice way to do" with respect to embedding a document. Provide your design consideration if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not have a multi-collection Map / Reduce. MongoDB does not have any JOIN syntax and may not be very good for ad-hoc joins. You will need to denormalize this data in some way.

You have a few options:

**Option #1: Embed the age with the vote.**

```
{Title:'Title1', vote:[{name:'a', age:12}]}
```

**Option #2: Keep a counter of the ages**

```
{Title:'Title1', vote:[a, b], age: { "12" : 1, "22" : 1 }}
```

**Option #3: Do a "manual" join**

Your last option is to write script/code that does a `for` loop over both collections and merges the data correctly.

So you would loop over `post` and output a collection with the title and the list of votes. Then you would loop through the new collection and update the ages by looking up each `user`.

**My suggestion**

Go with #1 or #2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
{name:'a', age:12}
```

It is easier to add a new field to user document and maintain it in each vote update.Of course, you can enjoy to use map reduce to analysis your data.

```
{name:'a', age:12, voteTitle:["Title1","Title2","Title3","Title4"]}
```