# want to merge two collection in mongo db using map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have two collection as bellow products has reference of user. i search product by name & in return i  want combine output of product and user using map reduce method

```
user collection
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52ac5dd1fb670c2007000000"),
  "company" : {
    "about" : "This is textile machinery dealer",
    "contactAddress" : [{
        "address" : "abcd",
        "city" : "52ac4bc6fb670c1007000000",
        "zipcode" : "39as46as80"
      },{
        "address" : "abcd",
        "city" : "52ac4bc6fb670c1007000000",
        "zipcode" : "39as46as80"
      }],
    "fax" : "58784868",
    "mainProducts" : "ads,asd,asd",
    "mobileNumber" : "9537236588",
    "name" : "krishna steels",
    }
  "user" : ObjectId("52ac4eb7fb670c0c07000000")
}

product colletion
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52ac5722fb670cf806000002"),
  "category" : "52a2a9cc48a508b80e00001d",
  "deliveryTime" : "10 days after received the ",
  "price" : {
    "minPrice" : "2000",
    "maxPrice" : "3000",
    "perUnit" : "5288ac6f7c104203e0976851",
    "currency" : "INR"
  },
  "productName" : "New Mobile Solar Charger with Carabiner",
  "rejectReason" : "",
  "status" : 1,
  "user" : ObjectId("52ac4eb7fb670c0c07000000")
}
```

Comment: Have you searched Google yet?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. Mongo support Map Reduce only on one collection. You could try to fetch and merge in a java collection. Couple of days back I solved a similar problem using java collection.

[Click to see similar response about joins and multi collection not supported in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964160/mongodb-map-reduce-across-2-collection).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using two map reduces.

You run your first MR and then you `reduce` out the second MR onto the results of the first.

You **shouldn't** do this though. JOINs are not designed to be done through MR, in fact it sounds like you are trying to do this MR with `inline` output which in itself is a very bad idea.

MRs are **not** designed to run inline to the application.

You would be better off doing the JOIN else where.